# Storing DOM elements to be used as news section for website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dom

I have been able to use the `file_get_contents` to go through a websites news section and grab the title text from each article. How would I then store that information and use it in a section on my website?

my php:

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents("https://www.coindesk.com/category/news/");

$dom = new DomDocument();
$internalErrors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_use_internal_errors($internalErrors);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$classname="fade";
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    echo $node->nodeValue."<br>"; 
} 
?>
```

where I want to store it:

```
<div id="box5" class="toggle" style="display: none;">
        <div id="services" class="services">
                <div class="container" >
                    <div class="service-head text-center">
                        <h2>NEWS</h2>
                        <span> </span>

                    </div>
                <button class="accordion">STORE THE POST TITLE HERE</button>
                <div class="panel1">
                  <p>STORE THE POST SUMMARY HERE WITH LINKS TO ARTICLE</p>
                </div>

                <button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
                <div class="panel1">
                  <p></p>
                </div>

                <button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
                <div class="panel1">
                  <p></p>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to generate new pages for each extraction and save as different html files or you want to use one single template and get data from some storage like a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly straightforward to do - once the XPath expressions have matched the content you store the node contents into an array or object which can be used later in the same page, saved to db or added to a session to use on a-n-other page.

```
/* source url */
$url='https://www.coindesk.com/category/news/';

/* store results in this array */
$output=array();

/* XPath expressions */
$exp=new stdClass;
$exp->articles='//div[@id="content"]/div[ contains(@class,"article") ]/div[@class="post-info"]';
$exp->title='h3/a';
$exp->description='p[@class="desc"]';

/* Load the source url directly into DOMDocument */
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->standalone=true;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->substituteEntities=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->formatOutput=true;
$dom->loadHTMLFile( $url );
libxml_clear_errors();

/* Query the DOM and process nodes found */
$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query( $exp->articles );

if( !empty( $col ) && $col->length > 0 ){
    foreach( $col as $node ){
        $output[]=(object)array(
            'title'         =>  $xp->query($exp->title,$node)->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'description'   =>  $xp->query($exp->description,$node)->item(0)->nodeValue
        );
    }
}
$dom = $xp = $col = $node = null;


/* 
    The contents of the scrape are stored in the $output array
    and can be used whereever on the page you wish - or stored
    as a session variable and used elsewhere etc etc
*/
if( !empty( $output ) ){
    /*
        removed `display:none` from div below.....
    */
    echo "
    <div id='box5' class='toggle'>
        <div id='services' class='services'>
            <div class='container' >
                <div class='service-head text-center'>
                    <h2>NEWS</h2>
                    <span> </span>
                </div>";

    /* iterate through output array where each member is an object */
    foreach( $output as $i => $obj ){
        echo "
                <button class='accordion'>{$obj->title}</button>
                <div class='panel1'>
                    <p>{$obj->description}</p>
                </div>";
    }

    echo "
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
```

Comment: Holy Moly! works brilliantly thank you so much!! quick question. I'm getting a fair amount of warnings and erros before the content is loaded. is that something I can remove? eg 'Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): htmlParseEntityRef:'

Comment: Strange: I don't get any errors or warnings with the above code ~ are you using it verbatim?

Comment: It seems to work fine when I add the libxml clear errors as I did in the original code. seriously thank you i've been scratching my head for hours over this. If you're ever in Melbourne, Aus. Drinks on me.